# An inequality in the proof of Hopf's lemma about the directional derivative at the boundary

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

In their book *Morse index of solutions of nonlinear elliptic equations*, Damascelli and Pacella state and prove the following form of Hopf's lemma:

> Let $B = B(y, r_1)$ be a ball, $x_0 \in \partial B$ and $v \in H^1(B) \cap C^0(B \cup \{x_0\}$ be a weak solution of $-\Delta v + c(x)v \geq 0$ in $B$, with $c \in L^\infty(B)$. Assume further that $v > 0$ in $B$ and $v(x_0) = 0$. Then $\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}(x_0) > 0$ for every inner direction $s$, in the sense that
> $$
> \liminf_{t \to 0^+} \frac{v(x_0 + ts) - v(x_0)}{t} > 0 
> $$
> whenever $(y - x_0) \cdot s > 0$.

The idea of the proof is to define $z(x) =e^{-\alpha r_1^2} - e^{-\alpha |x-y|^2}$ in $A = B(y, r_1) \setminus B(y, r_1/2)$, where $\alpha$ is a parameter that will later be picked big enough, and, using the continuity of the trace, apply the weak maximum principle for $w = v + \varepsilon z$ in $A$. Note that
$$
\Delta z = - e^{-\alpha|x - y|^2}(4\alpha^2|x - y|^2 - 2 \alpha N)
$$
Now, in a part of the proof the following chain of inequalities is presented:
$$
- \Delta z + c(x) z = e^{- \alpha |x - y|^2} \left(4 \alpha^2 |x - y|^2 - 2 \alpha N + c(x) \frac{e^{-\alpha r_1^2}}{e^{- \alpha|x - y|^2}} - c(x) \right)\\ 
\geq e^{- \alpha |x - y|^2} \left(4 \alpha^2 \frac{r_1^2}{4} - 2 \alpha N - \|c\|_\infty \right) \\
(*) \quad \geq e^{r_1^2/4}\left(4 \alpha^2 \left(\frac{r_1^2}{4} \right)^2 - 2 \alpha N - \|c\|_\infty \right) \\
> 0
$$

I will be the most grateful for an explanation of the inequality marked with an $(*)$, namely from the second to the third line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe if we take $r_1$ small enough? The Lemma in question is to be used in the following theorem, whose proof in turn allows us to take $r_1$ as small as we want

Comment: The proof works if we take $-r_1^2/4$ in the exponent and ignore the square of $r_1^2/4$ inside the parenthesis. Probably just a misprint.